# Getting incorrect answer in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner and wrote this code to calculate area of circle but it gives an incorrect [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPm9Y.png).  If I put radius = 7, then area should be `22/7*7*7` = `22*7` = `154` but I get 147.00. Why is that so?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float aoc (float radius);

int main()
{
    float answer, radius;
    printf("Enter value of radius");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    answer=aoc(radius);
    printf("area of circle is %f",answer);
    getch();    
}

float aoc (float radius)
{
    float area = 22*radius*(1/7*radius);
    return(area);   
}
```

Comment: Odd — since `1/7` is `0`, I'd expect to get 0 as the answer.  Maybe you had `1.0/7.0` in mind?  And `355 / 113` is a much better approximation to π than `22 / 7` is.

Comment: The program, as shown, prints `0.00`:  https://ideone.com/z92K8a
Output: `Enter value of radiusarea of circle is 0.000000`

Comment: Observation: 3 * 49 = 147.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float(1/7) = 0, You can do -

```
float area = 22*radius*(1.0/7.0*radius);
```

Or this-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float aoc (float radius);

int main()
{
    float answer, radius;
    printf("Enter value of radius");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    answer=aoc(radius);
    printf("area of circle is %f",answer);
    getch();
    
}

float aoc (float radius)
{
    float area = (22*radius*radius)/7;
    return(area);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 22/7. Just declare a global variable `pi=3.14.`

Here's your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float PI=3.14;

float aoc (float radius);

int main()
{
    float answer, radius;
    printf("Enter value of radius");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    answer=aoc(radius);
    printf("area of circle is %f",answer);
    return 0;
    
}

float aoc (float radius)
{
    float area = PI*radius*radius;
    return(area);   
}
```

Comment: `22.0 / 7.0` is a better approximation to π than `3.14`; and `355.0 / 113.0` (`3.14159292035398230088`) is far better than either of those.